# Update to 4.1.2 on a Nexus S with CWM and broken USB port

Tags: updates, samsung-nexus-s

I have a Nexus S, rooted, with CWM and a stock 4.0.4 ROM. The USB port is broken(only charging works), so how do I go to stock 4.1.2 update?

If there is a way to manually apply OTA, that'd be great. Or a way to fix the USB port, but I think that's widely reported and not really fixed.

I tried the system > updates (and clearing Google services framework trick) and it shows upto date, ie. no new OTA. Perhaps because I have a custom recovery?

Answer (score 1):

If you can find someone else with an unlocked Nexus S, you can use nandroid backups to do everything on their device and then duplicate efforts to your device, like so: 
Let's call your phone Device A and theirs Device B. 
Boot into recovery on both devices, then make a nandroid backup of each device, which I will call Nandroid A and Nandroid B, for each phone. 
 Using some sort of wireless file-transfer application ([AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), [Samba Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.sambaserver), etc), transfer the nandroid backups to a computer for safekeeping, and then put Nandroid A onto Device B and boot into recovery on Device B. Wipe the cache, dalvik cache, system partition, and data partition, then restore Nandroid A onto Device B. Once the restore is complete, boot Device B normally and perform the OTA update as you would under normal conditions.
Reboot into Recovery on Device B after installing the update, and make a new nandroid backup which I will call Nandroid A2. Then, move files around wirelessly as outlined above and wipe Device A and restore Nandroid A2 to Device A. Finally, wipe Device B and restore Nandroid B to Device B and give it back to your much-indebted-to friend.

Be careful when you wipe before a restore /not/ to wipe the internal storage on the device. The Nexus S doesn't have an SD card slot, otherwise I'd just advise you remove the SD card altogether while restoring... But [TWRP](http://teamw.in/project/twrp) has a pretty straightforward checkbox that will help you make sure you aren't wiping your internal storage.

Yes, this method is roundabout and long-winded, and yes, it does require access to hardware that you may not be able to get your hands on. But it *will* work.

Comment: You could also give [OTA Updater](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.otaupdater) a shot, though I'm not entirely sure if it'll play nice with your setup. Can't really hurt it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use an app like [WiFi File Trasnfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer&hl=en) to transfer the [stock image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) to your phone and then flash it using whatever recovery you're using.

Comment: I have Airdroid for transfer but since 4.1, Ota packages cannot be flashed via custom recovery. It gives a 'status 7' error.

Comment: @Sumesh 'status 7' error is one of insufficient space, incorrect fingerprint, file corrupted....

Comment: Status 7 is known to occur when trying to flash Ota in custom recovery, since 4.2,  even when space and corruption issues do not occur. I've been unable to find a workaround. I have a backup of stock ROM via CWM, reverted to it but Ota isn't showing up even then.

Comment: Unlocked bootloader == no OTA in most cases. I think I even remember my Nexus 4 giving that warning when I was rooting it.